# Unable to call a test method from another test class in selenium using page factory

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, page-factory

I do have a page object and test class for sign_in functionality,while calling that test sign_in method into another test class it is showing nullpointerexception, that signin has to reuse for different functionality it mandatory to sign-in to enter into another functionality.

```
        public class VerifySignIn extends BaseClass{
        public SignIn sign;
        public String expectedSignpage = "Checkmark Canada Cloud Payroll | 
        Dashboard";

        @Test(priority=1)
        public void VerifySigninpage() {
        try {
        test = report.startTest("Verify Signin Test");
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test Started" + test.getStartedTime());
        sign = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SignIn.class);
        sign.enterEmailID(userid);
        sign.enterPassword(pwd);
        sign.clickSigninBtn();
        String dashboardTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedSignpage, dashboardTitle);
        System.out.println("the title after signin is: "+dashboardTitle);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Test signin not executed msg is: " + 
        e.getMessage());
        }
        }
        }

i have called that signin method in this class it show `NullPointerException` COULD ANYONE HELP ME,how to call `@test` method of one class into another `@test` method of another class.how to write sign-in functionality using `PageFactory` so it can reuse for different functionality.


public class VerifyAddOtherDeductions extends BaseClass {
public SignIn sign;
public AddOtherDeductions deductions;
String expectedtitle="Checkmark Canada Cloud Payroll | Deductions";

@Test(priority=1)
  public void verifySignIn() {
    try {
        test = report.startTest("Verify to signin Test");
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test Started" + test.getStartedTime());
        sign=PageFactory.initElements(driver, SignIn.class);
        sign.enterEmailID(userid);
        sign.enterPassword(pwd);
        sign.clickSigninBtn();
        String dashboardTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("After signin page title is: "+dashboardTitle);
    } catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("verify signin exception is: "+e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Test(priority=2)
public void verifyOtherDeductionsAddFromList() {
    test = report.startTest("Verify OtherDeductions Add From List Test");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test Started" + test.getStartedTime());
    deductions=PageFactory.initElements(driver, AddOtherDeductions.class);
    deductions.companySetupClick();
    deductions.clickOtherDeductions();
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), expectedtitle);
    deductions.addFromListBtn();
    deductions.selectFromList();
    deductions.addList();
    deductions.confirmbtnclick();
    }


    package com.baseclass;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import com.utilities.ReadConfig;

public class BaseClass {
    ReadConfig readconfig = new ReadConfig();
    public String baseurl = readconfig.getApplicationURL();
    public String userid = readconfig.getUserId();
    public String pwd = readconfig.getPassword();
    public String departmentname=readconfig.departmentName();
    public WebDriver driver;
    public static Logger logger;

    public static String dest;
    public static String time;

    public static ExtentReports report;
    public static ExtentTest test;

    public static String takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            // System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); // 2016/11/16 12:08:43

            time = dateFormat.format(date);
            // System.out.println("Time is" + time);
            TakesScreenshot scrnshot = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
            File src = scrnshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            dest = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Screenshots\\" + time + ".png";
            File destination = new File(dest);
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, destination);
            System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Screenshot error is :" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return dest;
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void reportSetup() {
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter timelapse= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
                        ZonedDateTime zone= ZonedDateTime.now();
                    String reportTime=  timelapse.format(zone);
            String repName = "Test-Report-" + reportTime + ".html";
            report = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/ExtentReport/" + repName, true);
            report.addSystemInfo("HostName", "phani").addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA")
                    .addSystemInfo("User", "Ambadas").addSystemInfo("Project Name", "Automation Demo");
            report.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\extent-config.xml"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Report issue is :" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void getReport(ITestResult result) {
        try {
            String screenshot = takeScreenshot(driver);
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {

                test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, result.getThrowable());
                test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Below is the screen shot:-" + test.addScreenCapture(screenshot));
                test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Fail is:- " + result.getName());

            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
                test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case pass is:- " + result.getName());
                //test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Below is the screen shot:-" + test.addScreenCapture(screenshot));
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
                test.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "test Case skip is:- " + result.getName());
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.STARTED) {
                test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test Case started");

            }
            report.endTest(test);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Report generation exception is :" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void endTest() {
        report.flush();
        report.close();
    }

    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass
    public void baseSetup(String browser) {
        Logger.getLogger("Payroll");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", readconfig.getChromePath());
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", readconfig.getFirefoxPath());
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browser.equals("ie")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", readconfig.getIEPath());
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseurl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();

}
```

}

I have mentioned the same signin menthod in to another test class,so iam mentioning same signin method for different classes,ANY HELP ME HOW TO CALL SIGNIN METHOD INSTEAD OF WRITING LENGTHY CODE FOR DIFFERNT FUNCTIONALITY CLASSES

Comment: Please show your code!  What does your base class that instantiates the driver look like.  How does your test class pull in an instantiated driver object.  How does your page object class get an instantiated driver object?

Comment: This may be useful to look at, and may help you out: http://github.com/ardesco/Selenium-Maven-template

Comment: HI Ardesco, I have inserted code plz check once.

Comment: So I see 2 classes that extend `BaseClass`, but I still don't know what base class does.  Does you base class have a `@BeforeMethod` or `@BeforeClass` that instantiates your driver object?

Comment: so, if i had beforemethod or beforeclass then sign test has to be there in that annotations right

Comment: No `@BeforeMethod` or `@BeforeClass` would be called before your test is run (hence the name of the annotations).  We would need to see the code in your `BaseClass` to have a chance of helping you.

Comment: no i don't have BeforeMethod or BeforeClass in BaseClass

Comment: We still need to see your BaseClass code to see what it is doing.  You are using a `driver` object in your tests but it's not clear where it comes from.  The assumption is that it's defined in your `BaseClass`, but until we see it we won't know.  I'm guessing that there is an error in your `BaseClass` which results in your driver object not being instantiated which causes the `NullPointerException`

Comment: i have inserted base class check once

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere, what's the value of the String being passed in using the `browser` parameter?  Your code does not have a fallback if an unrecognised browser String is passed in, I suspect the most likely cause for your failure is that you are sending in an unrecognised browser name (note that the browser String your code is expecting is lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, I have two ways to handle this situation:
1) Include 'VerifySigninpage' method code in @BeforeTest of BaseClass. By default, login functionality can be handled Before actual test starts and do specific homepage/ any other page test without having dependency on SignIn
2) Write SignIn method as instance method in separate class and call SignIn method in your @Test method by creating an Object for LoginFunctionality class

```
VerifySignIn page = new VerifySignIn();
page.SignIn();
```

Comment: i have tried all possible things to call but i didn't get

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you are passing in an invalid browser parameter that is either not lowercase, or is not equal to `chrome`, `firefox` or `ie`.  I've tweaked your code to default to Firefox if the browser parameter passed in has not been set/can't be matched and I've also forced the passed in parameter to lower case to deal with a potential error due to an input like `Firefox`:

```
@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeClass
public void baseSetup(String browser) {
    //I assigned the logger here since it wasn't being done, you may not want to do this
    logger = Logger.getLogger("Payroll");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    switch (browser.toLowerCase()) {
        case "chrome": {
            //Setting a property like this is generally bad practice, you may be overwriting a property that has already been set on a build agent
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", readconfig.getChromePath());
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        }
        case "ie": {
            //Setting a property like this is generally bad practice, you may be overwriting a property that has already been set on a build agent
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", readconfig.getIEPath());
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            break;
        }
        case "firefox": {
            //Setting a property like this is generally bad practice, you may be overwriting a property that has already been set on a build agent
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", readconfig.getFirefoxPath());
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            //Set a default of firefox, you can change this to whatever you want.
            logger.info(String.format("Unable to resolve %s, defaulting to `firefox`...", browser));
            //Setting a property like this is generally bad practice, you may be overwriting a property that has already been set on a build agent
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", readconfig.getFirefoxPath());
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
    }

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Don't use implicit waits, use explicit waits instead.  Any checks to make sure a element does not exist will take 50 seconds
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(baseurl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    //Don't use driver.close() for cleanup!
    //It will throw an additional exception if the browser window has already been closed due to error
    driver.quit();
}
```

I've added comments inline to explain the changes I have made and point out obvious problems I can see.  This should hopefully get you up and running and log out the value passed in as the parameter `browser` so that you can see what is being sent in if it's not one of the expected values.

Comment: HI Ardesco,  
ok plz tell how to set a property to launch browser, you it is bad way of writing ri8.

Comment: Selenium checks for an environmental variable on the local machine to work out where the browser is installed.  The idea is that when you create your build node, or set up your local dev box you install a local copy of the relevant driver binary and then set a system environmental variables that points to the location of the binary.  This way you can make sure that you have a matched browser/browser driver version that will just work.